# Time Complexity Of Binary Tree Subtree Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursion, trees, data-structure

Given two binary trees, check whether one is a subtree of another one. This is my algorithm. Basically, it says:

> For two binary trees A and B, A is a subtree of B if they are the same tree. If they are not the same tree, then check whether A is a subtree of B.left or a subtree of B.right.

```
public boolean isSubtree(TreeNode s, TreeNode t) {
    if (s == null || t == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (sameTree(s, t)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isSubtree(s.left, t) || isSubtree(s.right, t);
    }
}
public boolean sameTree(TreeNode A, TreeNode B) {
    if (A == null && B == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((A == null && B != null) || (A != null && B == null)) {
        return false;
    }
    return A.val == B.val && sameTree(A.left, B.left) && sameTree(A.right, B.right);
}
```

This algorithm works; but my head hurts when I try to analyze the space + time complexity.

For time complexity, I made the following recurrence:

> Let **n** = nodes in B (the bigger tree), and **m** = nodes in A (the smaller tree)
>
> **T(n,m) = min(m, n) + 2 * T(n/2, m)**

The logic for the above is that "sameTree" will always fully traverse the smaller of its two arguments. And we only recurse on **n**, so only that one gets halved in the recursive call.

However, I do not know how to resolve the recurrence. Does anyone have any ideas?

Also, what is the space complexity? I argue it is, in the worst case, the minimum of **n** and **m** and, in the best case, the logarithm base two of their minimum (assuming the tree is relatively balanced). These are due to the stack of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a recurrence, it's O(nm). (In the worst case, you're visiting m nodes for each node in the n-nodes tree). The space complexity is O(max(n,m)) (or the log if you know the trees are balanced, however, it's the maximum you need to take, not the minimum).

PS: one can also have an O(n) test, see for instance https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-binary-tree-subtree-another-binary-tree-set-2/ .